# Create and Expand the column with all records.

Tags: powerbi

As a newbie to Power BI, requesting help.
**I am having a data set like below,**

```
ID      LOCATION    PACKAGE
1234    ABC         BASE
4567    DEF         GOLD
7900    GHI         SILVER 
11233   JKL         PLATINUM 
14566   MNO         PLATINUM 
17899   PQR         GOLD
21232   STU         SILVER
```

The list goes up to a million rows, but every package has different numbers of products in them.

**Like below.**

```
PKG   PRODS MANU    PKG   PRODS MANU    PKG   PRODS MANU    PKG P      RODS MANU
BASE    11  XYZ     SILVER  11  XYZ     GOLD    11  XYZ     PLATINUM    11  XYZ
BASE    12  XYZ     SILVER  12  XYZ     GOLD    12  XYZ     PLATINUM    12  XYZ
BASE    13  XYZ     SILVER  13  XYZ     GOLD    13  XYZ     PLATINUM    13  XYZ
BASE    14  XYZ     SILVER  14  XYZ     GOLD    14  XYZ     PLATINUM    14  XYZ
BASE    15  GHY     SILVER  15  GHY     GOLD    15  GHY     PLATINUM    15  GHY
BASE    16  GHY     SILVER  16  GHY     GOLD    16  GHY     PLATINUM    16  GHY
BASE    17  GHY     SILVER  17  GHY     GOLD    17  GHY     PLATINUM    17  GHY
BASE    18  QWE     SILVER  18  QWE     GOLD    18  QWE     PLATINUM    18  QWE
BASE    19  QWE     SILVER  19  QWE     GOLD    19  QWE     PLATINUM    19  QWE
                    SILVER  29  XYZ     GOLD    29  XYZ     PLATINUM    29  XYZ
                    SILVER  30  XYZ     GOLD    30  XYZ     PLATINUM    30  XYZ
                    SILVER  31  XYZ     GOLD    31  XYZ     PLATINUM    31  XYZ
                    SILVER  32  QWE     GOLD    32  QWE     PLATINUM    32  QWE
                    SILVER  33  GHY     GOLD    33  GHY     PLATINUM    33  GHY
                                        GOLD    64  KLJ     PLATINUM    64  KLJ
                                        GOLD    65  XYZ     PLATINUM    65  XYZ
                                        GOLD    66  XYZ     PLATINUM    66  XYZ
                                        GOLD    67  QWE     PLATINUM    67  QWE
                                        GOLD    68  KLJ     PLATINUM    68  KLJ
                                        GOLD    69  KLJ     PLATINUM    69  KLJ
                                                            PLATINUM    100 XYZ
                                                            PLATINUM    101 QWE
                                                            PLATINUM    102 GHY
                                                            PLATINUM    103 KLJ
                                                            PLATINUM    104 XYZ
```

I am unable to create the relationship between two tables because PBI says it must have some unique values.

I need the count of every product and count of every package through which this product is being delivered.

How to do it?

I was thinking about generating a custom column where all the products shall be 'tabled' along with other details and then expanding it but don't know how to do it.

Will it do the trick?

Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can begin at the data model level by creating another table that contains one unique row per PACKAGE:  BASE, SILVER, GOLD, PLATINUM, etc.

Then, you can create relationships between this new table and the two tables you showed us.

Now that your two data tables are connected (indirectly), you can write measures to obtain the metrics you need.